# How can I get attribute in class

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get attribute in class but it doesn't work

I using Django, html, php, query

```
    <div id="yui_patched_v3_18_1_1_1556713475044_913" 
class="diagram-node-task yui3-widget yui3-overlay diagram-node yui3-widget-positioned yui3-widget-stacked"  
tabindex="1" data-nodeid="diagramNode_field_task923"  
style="height: 70px; width: 70px; left: 441px; top: 161px; z-index: 100;">
```

so i do it this one

```
$(".diagram-node-task yui3-widget yui3-overlay diagram-node yui3-widget-positioned yui3-widget-stacked").attr('style')
```

and this one

```
$(".diagram-node-task yui3-widget yui3-overlay diagram-node yui3-widget-positioned yui3-widget-stacked").css('width')
```

But they are not work (they show me undefined)

I want get style like width, height in this code

Comment: use this `console.log($(".diagram-node-task.yui3-widget.yui3-overlay.diagram-node.yui3-widget-positioned.yui3-widget-stacked").attr("style"))` you need to add `.` for class selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this

```
let style = $(".diagram-node-task.yui3-widget.yui3-overlay.diagram-node.yui3-widget-positioned.yui3-widget-stacked").attr('style');
console.log(style);
```

Because all classes in same div you need add query selector as `.diagram-node-task.yui3-widget.yui3-overlay.diagram-node.yui3-widget-positioned.yui3-widget-stacked`

```js
let style = $(".diagram-node-task.yui3-widget.yui3-overlay.diagram-node.yui3-widget-positioned.yui3-widget-stacked").attr('style');
console.log(style);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yui_patched_v3_18_1_1_1556713475044_913" 
class="diagram-node-task yui3-widget yui3-overlay diagram-node yui3-widget-positioned yui3-widget-stacked"  
tabindex="1" data-nodeid="diagramNode_field_task923"  
style="height: 70px; width: 70px; left: 441px; top: 161px; z-index: 100;">
```

Answer (score 0):

For selecting a particular `style` use `css()` .You can use just one class to get the attribute.Hope this helps

```js
var style = $(".yui3-widget-stacked").attr('style')
var width= $(".yui3-widget-stacked").css('width')

console.log("Style: "+style)
console.log("Width: "+width)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yui_patched_v3_18_1_1_1556713475044_913" 
class="diagram-node-task yui3-widget yui3-overlay diagram-node yui3-widget-positioned yui3-widget-stacked"  
tabindex="1" data-nodeid="diagramNode_field_task923"  
style="height: 70px; width: 70px; left: 441px; top: 161px; z-index: 100;">
```